# Dependeny error in installing postgreSQL 9.6

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I am getting this error while installing postgreSQL in odoo10:

```
root@aboorva:~# sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-9.6 : Depends: postgresql-common (>= 171~) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
                  Recommends: postgresql-contrib-9.6 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: sysstat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: The error should be copied and pasted in your post! Run `sudo apt-get -f install postgresql-9.6`

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: The same problem occurred, I solved it based on this link https://superuser.com/questions/1366175/unmet-dependencies-for-postgresql-10-under-ubuntu-16-04-5-lts-xenial/1366209#1366209?newreg=2b2e728f9a074b7a938c55c8460b3c85

Answer (score 2):

It's telling you that your libraries for your system don't allow you to install that version of postgres, since you asked for a specific version upon installing.

If you just want postgres and don't care about the specific version, try:

```
sudo apt-get install postgres
```

If you want that specific version and need it, you need to remove the `libsystem0` package and whatever is keeping it installed.

It's also possible your system has downloaded and upgraded some of it's packages or was stopped while doing a package update. In that case you should run this command to install any missing packages waiting to be processed:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

It's also worth noting that you may want to remove any version of postgres you have before trying to install the new ones:

```
sudo apt-get remove postgres*
```

Comment: 9.5 is the latest version for 16.04.  The postgresql installer scripts will not uninstall a  previous version, but will use another port (one higher) to allow running the two versions in parallel until you are satisfied the new version works for you. Then you may safely remove the old version.